# Notify when user is in my location in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am looking for an easy way to check if a user is at my location (50m) radius if notify me.

Right now I have a service running every two minutes getting position of each user comparing it and then notifying if user in same location.

Can this be done using promixityalert: http://goo.gl/9I857T?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use [GeoFencing, google play services](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Comment: @user2450263 : Isn't geofencing require LAT AND LONG value for a particular place? If so then that is problem because for e.g : If User A wants alert when user B and User C are near him. And user A keeps moving? then how does geofencing will work?

Comment: aren't you using lat,long for comparing? ***getting position of user*** means in what sense? can you post some code, it may help

Comment: I don't have the code right now but I have the psuedo code.

1. First am taking my current location (User A)
2. Then I am taking user's current location (User B)
3. I am checking the user A's current location with User B's current location 
4. If user B is around 20M radius, then I just give notification. 

Above I am running in a service. setting an alarm for every 2 mins. 

I am looking for a better and faster way to do this because alarm manager are not reliable. 

So in geofencing (Point of interest is static) so how could I use the above logic with geofencing?

Comment: why the alarm for every 2 mins? if its for obtaining location, you can use `setInterval()`/`fastestInterval()`, i'd suggest increase the radius, compare location's accuracy also, the current location values and actual location could change fast. Also, based on the geofencing logic, it should work but would be too many requests so yeah good to avoid it then, i have not used it dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Instead ProximityAlert I would use Geofences.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Is newer and does a more effective use of the battery

In your case, you can have a service that sends to the other device the current location every X minutes, so it can update the Geofence. The problem that I see is that there would be a lot of calls, spending battery and the data plan.

A good approach is to use the Location Services API, you can detect if a user is standing or moving.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

Using this and sending new locations only when the user is moving you will be able to reduce the amount of calls.

Parse is another option as @thepace mention. It is easy to use and whit it would be easy to implement what you are trying to do, but is not free :(

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
Issue: Check if any user (multiple and variable location) is within specific radius of my current location(variable).

Solution: 
1. Parse.com
a) Ensure every user has their location updated in Parse DB including yours.
   https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android
b) Use push notificaitons: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#setup/Android 
   1> Create a channel wherein only you are subscribed.
   2> Create your installation query and send notification to it to the channel subscribed.
```

Comment: It will work. The link was to guide you towards its implementation.

Comment: The problem that I figured out after checking the proximity is that it requires lat, long and radius, but the problem here is that my location is not static. I keep moving - in that case How do use proximity?

Comment: One solution is to cancel the pendingIntent and recreate it on onLocationChanged() in your case with the updated co-ordinates.

Comment: Is the user fixed? Are their multiple users (considering scalability of your feature)?

Comment: The user is not fixed. But I have an option say give me alert when specific person is near by.

Comment: Seems the user is moving and so are you. If everyone has the app installed, one good solution is using Parse to store the data of each user and query it to get if you enter proximity of any user. https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android

Comment: To avoid a service running in background everytime, you could subscribe to pushNotification of users's location including yours. Whenever they change, check the proximity and alert/notify.

Comment: Do you think I can use push notification using GCM? Also I think parse.com is not free? :(

Comment: GCM push notification won't be using the locations of all the user because it doesn't have any info. Also for Parse, I think upto a certain limit its free. https://www.parse.com/plans